# How to add iframes dynamically through code, in liferay

Tags: java, iframe, liferay, portlet, portal

I have a scenario in which users who are created in the liferay will be assigned tools(in the form of iframe). **The number of iframes will differ for each user, and when the user logs in, that many number of iframes should come up automatically in his public page**.

How can I achieve this ? Is there a way I can save this in preferences of public pages(which will be unique for each user) ? Or should I be using the DB to achieve the same?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding of iframes to liferay can be done dynamically from code, and this is achieved by following code:

```
            long companyId = themeDisplay.getCompanyId();
        long ownerId = PortletKeys.PREFS_OWNER_ID_DEFAULT;
        int ownerType = PortletKeys.PREFS_OWNER_TYPE_LAYOUT;
        Layout layout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayout(themeDisplay.getPlid());
        LayoutTypePortlet layoutTypePortlet = (LayoutTypePortlet) layout.getLayoutType();
        String iframePortletId = layoutTypePortlet.addPortletId(themeDisplay.getUserId(),PortletKeys.IFRAME,"column-2",-1);
        PortletPreferences prefs = PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.getPreferences(companyId,ownerId,ownerType,layout.getPlid(),iframePortletId);
        prefs.setValue("src", "http://www.google.com");
        com.liferay.portal.model.PortletPreferences objPortletPref=PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.updatePreferences(ownerId, ownerType,                     layout.getPlid(), iframePortletId, prefs);
        LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLayout(layout.getGroupId(),layout.isPrivateLayout(),layout.getLayoutId(),layout.getTypeSettings());
```

This will add an iframe dynamically.

Thank you.